# Why does the variable double randomly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, variables, methods

```
class OrangeTree
  attr_accessor :one_year_passes, :age, :orange_count, :growth, :length

  def initialize
    @length = 0
    #@one_year_passes = one_year_passes
    @age = 0
    @orange_count = 0
    @growth = growth
  end

  def height
    if self.age <= 0
        self.length = 0
        growth
    else 
        growth
    end
  end

  def growth
    self.length += 12
    years
  end

  def years
    if self.length >= 12
        self.age = self.length / 12
        #num_oranges
    else
        self.age = 0
        height
    end
  end
```

I don't know if my question made much sense, but I'm making an orange tree class that grows and it's growth affects it's age, which ultimately affects the numbers of oranges it has. Anyways, the problem I'm facing is that when I call the height method on an instance it eventually passes through the growth method, which makes it grow 12 units/inches, but once it goes to the years method and the conditional statement is tried length goes from 12 to 24 without me doing anything. If I call self.length before that conditional 12 will print out, but if I call after the conditional 24 is printed, which ultimately means self.age = 2 instead of 1. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set `@growth` to `0` in initialize method. Currently you call method `growth` once during initialization, then second time calling `height` on instance, hence receiving `age == 2`.

Comment: So if @growth was set to growth and not 0, would that mean the growth method is run during the initialize method?